# Bounded buffer problem - Producer producing the data but consumer not consuming it

Tags: java, multithreading, buffer, buffer-overflow, java-threads

I am writing a bound buffer program, the producer produces the data based on the size of the buffer, but the consumer is not consuming it, thus not solving the problem. What am I missing?

Buffer class:

```
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class SharedBuffer {
    
    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    
    int bufferCapacity = 5;

}
```

Producer class:

```
public class Producer extends SharedBuffer implements Runnable {
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int currentValue = 0;
        while(true) {
            synchronized(this){
                
                while(queue.size() == bufferCapacity) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                
                System.out.println("Producer produced: " + currentValue);
                
                queue.add(currentValue++);
                
                notify();
                
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```

Consumer class:

```
public class Consumer extends SharedBuffer implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int currentItem;
        
        while(true) {
            synchronized(this) {
                
                while(queue.size() == 0) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                
                currentItem = queue.remove();
                
                System.out.println("Consumer consumed: " + currentItem);
                
                notify();
                
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        
    }

    
}
```

Main/Driver class:

```
public class driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Producer producer = new Producer();
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer();
        
        Thread producerThread = new Thread(producer);
        Thread consumerThread = new Thread(consumer);
        
        consumerThread.start();
        producerThread.start();
        
        
        producerThread.join();
        consumerThread.join();

    }

}
```

Output (The loop continues without exiting):

```
Producer produced: 0
Producer produced: 1
Producer produced: 2
Producer produced: 3
Producer produced: 4
```

The threads should be synchronized so that the buffer doesn't overflow with producer producing overflow data or goes underflow with the consumer trying to consume more data than it is present.

Comment: I'm just guessing the queue is filled up by the producer before the consumer has even started, so the producers notify() will never reach the consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Both - Producer and Consumer classes are extending the SharedBuffer class, and this way they each have their own separate instance of the queue - so when you add new tasks in Producer, Consumer dont see them.

Queue should be shared between instances of Producer and Consumer. To do it pass the same instance of SharedBuffer to both the Producer and Consumer classes. Below is example of how you can modify your main method:

```
public class driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        
        SharedBuffer sharedBuffer = new SharedBuffer();
        
        Producer producer = new Producer(sharedBuffer);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(sharedBuffer);
        
        Thread producerThread = new Thread(producer);
        Thread consumerThread = new Thread(consumer);
        
        consumerThread.start();
        producerThread.start();
        
        
        producerThread.join();
        consumerThread.join();

    }

}
```

... and of course, modify the constructors of your Producer and Consumer classes to accept a SharedBuffer instance and use it instead of creating a new one.

I also suggest you to change `synchronized(this) {` to `synchronized(queue) {`, to make code thread safe.